# How can I load a local HTML file into the UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

How can we load our own html file into the UIWebView?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7063276/how-to-load-local-html-file-into-uiwebview-iphone/24159166#24159166

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The following code will load an HTML file named `index.html` in your project folder:

```
[WebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
```

Comment: Apple's documentation suggests that using this method to load local HTML is not secure:

```To help you avoid being vulnerable to security attacks, be sure to use this method to load local HTML files; don’t use loadRequest:.```

I've recorded their suggestion (`loadHTMLString:baseURL:`) in my answer below.

Comment: Yeah, it didn't say that 5 years ago when I posted this answer. Always good to read the documentation. I'd delete this, but it's the accepted answer and has obviously helped a lot of people.

Answer (score 28):

Cody Gray is right but there's also this way :

```
// Load the html as a string from the file system
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"];
NSString *html = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

// Tell the web view to load it
[WebView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL]];
```

This is useful if you need to edit the html before you load it.

Comment: You're right but I would pass `[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]]` instead of `nil` for `baseURL`.

Comment: Ah yes - I'd not remembered about loading other resources from the html. I've edited my answer, thanks!

Comment: I'd pass [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleUrl]

Answer (score 6):

**Swift**

```
    guard let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("index", ofType: "html") else {
        return
    }

    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    self.webview.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL:url))
```

Answer (score 2):

By using following code you can load an html in an WebView.here web is web view obj and inde

```
Web.delegate = self;

[Web loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Apple's documentation suggests using `loadHTMLString:baseURL:`:

> Use the loadHTMLString:baseURL: method to begin loading local HTML files or the loadRequest: method to begin loading web content. Use the stopLoading method to stop loading, and the loading property to find out if a web view is in the process of loading.

The `loadHTMLString:baseURL:` documentation offers further reasoning:

> To help you avoid being vulnerable to security attacks, be sure to use this method to load local HTML files; don’t use loadRequest:.

This one might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29741277

Answer (score 0):

**Swift Version 2.1**

```
// load html to String with Encoding
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("policy", ofType: "html")
do {
    let fileHtml = try NSString(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    webView.loadHTMLString(fileHtml as String, baseURL: nil)
}
catch {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"privacy-Policy" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:nil];
NSData *htmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile];
[webView loadData:htmlData MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];
```