# How to load local html file into UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I'm trying to load a html file into my UIWebView but it won't work. Here's the stage: I have a folder called html_files in my project. Then I created a webView in interface builder and assigned an outlet to it in the viewController. This is the code I'm using to append the html file:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"html_files"];
    NSData *htmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile];
    [webView loadData:htmlData MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

That won't work and the UIWebView is blank. I'd appreciate some help.

Answer (score 278, accepted):

probably it is better to use NSString and load html document as follows:

**Objective-C**

```
NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample" ofType:@"html"];
NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL: [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL]];
```

**Swift**

```
let htmlFile = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("fileName", ofType: "html")
let html = try? String(contentsOfFile: htmlFile!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
webView.loadHTMLString(html!, baseURL: nil)
```

**Swift 3 has few changes:**

```
let htmlFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "intro", ofType: "html")
let html = try? String(contentsOfFile: htmlFile!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
webView.loadHTMLString(html!, baseURL: nil)
```

Did you try?

Also check that the resource was found by `pathForResource:ofType:inDirectory` call.

Comment: That didn't work, i did NSLog(@"%@",htmlFile); just to check and it says null.

Comment: So that mean resource not found. Check with just: NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample" ofType:@"html"]; without inDirectory

Comment: without inDirectory i got: **iPhone Simulator/4.3.2/Applications/49351078-9423-4A24-8E58-B2A059961097/WebviewTest.app/sample.html** but the html didn't show up in the screen it was still empty. I'm i missing something else? Here's the sample project: [http://www.box.net/shared/rb05b4ppjnbof1r33gh7](http://www.box.net/shared/rb05b4ppjnbof1r33gh7)

Comment: try to scroll up/down. you will see your html :)

Comment: you just need to fix frame of your webview

Comment: This answer has a lot of votes but seems to be out of date. Local image and CSS assets would not load using this approach. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17557309/893113) instead.

Comment: @user478681 In YOur Answer Code  shows NSString* htmlString=nil;  can you help whats the problem ?

Answer (score 92):

**EDIT 2016-05-27** - [`loadRequest` exposes "a universal Cross-Site Scripting vulnerability."](http://browser-shredders.blogspot.com/2014/02/ios-uiwebview-baseurl.html) Make sure you own every single asset that you load. If you load a bad script, it can load anything it wants.

If you need relative links to work locally, use this:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"my" withExtension:@"html"];
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

The bundle will search all subdirectories of the project to find `my.html`. (the directory structure gets flattened at build time)

If `my.html` has the tag `<img src="some.png">`, the webView will load `some.png` from your project.

Comment: I couldn't get the accepted answer on this page to work -- but this approach worked first time. iOS has moved on since the original answer, I think. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. What's different about this vs. the accepted answer is links in the HTML doc work.

Comment: According to Apple _To help you avoid being vulnerable to security attacks, be sure to use loadHTMLString:baseURL: to load local HTML files; don’t use loadRequest:._

Comment: Accepted answer is not working for me. Thanks @neal Ehardt this answer is working for me.

Comment: This only work for me if the html file isn't inside any folder

Answer (score 40):

by this you can load html file which is in your project Assets(bundle) to webView.

```
 UIWebView *web = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
    [web loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                                pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
```

may be this is useful to you.

Comment: that's the same i'm doing the only difference is that you're creating the webView programmatically. But thanks anyway

Comment: u get the path of that html file check by NSLog.

Comment: Target membership of html file should be checked otherwise the following exception will get thrown :-Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:isDirectory:]: nil string parameter'

Answer (score 9):

I guess you need to `allocate` and init your `webview` first::

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"html_files"];
    NSData *htmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile];
    webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
    [webView loadData:htmlData MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Answer (score 8):

**A Simple Copy-Paste code snippet:**

```
-(void)LoadLocalHtmlFile:(NSString *)fileName onWebVu:(UIWebView*)webVu
{
    [webVu loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:fileName ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
}
```

**Note:**

Make sure the html file's *Target membership* is checked otherwise following exception will get thrown :-

[image]

Terminating app due to uncaught exception

`'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:isDirectory:]: nil string parameter'`

Answer (score 6):

For Swift 3 and Swift 4:

```
let htmlFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "name_resource", ofType: "html")
let html = try! String(contentsOfFile: htmlFile!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
self.webView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil)
```

Comment: This won't load linked files such as <img src="..." />

Answer (score 5):

```
UIWebView *web=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    //[self.view addSubview:web];
    NSString *filePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"browser_demo" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:nil];
    [web loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWhttp://stackoverflow.com/review/first-postsithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]]];
```

Answer (score 4):

May be your HTML file doesn't support UTF-8 encoding, because the same code is working for me.

Or u can also these line of code:

```
NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Notes For Apple" ofType:@"htm" inDirectory:nil];
NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
[WebView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

Answer (score 4):

Here the way the working of HTML file with Jquery.

```
 _webview=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568)];
    [self.view addSubview:_webview];

    NSString *filePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"jquery" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:nil];

    NSLog(@"%@",filePath);
    NSString *htmlstring=[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

    [_webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]]];
                         or
    [_webview loadHTMLString:htmlstring baseURL:nil];
```

You can use either  the requests to call the HTML file in your UIWebview

Answer (score 3):

Make sure "html_files" is a directory in your app's main bundle, and not just a group in Xcode.

Answer (score 3):

A new way to do this using swift. The UIWebView is no more and WKWebView is the new class to load web pages, which ensures the Safari features to the web view.

```
    import WebKit

    let preferences = WKPreferences()
    preferences.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = false

    let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    configuration.preferences = preferences

    let webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.bounds, configuration: configuration)
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://nshipster.com"))
    webView.loadRequest(request)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Swift iOS:

 // get server url from the plist directory
        var htmlFile = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("animation_bg", ofType: "html")!
        var htmlString = NSString(contentsOfFile: htmlFile, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
        self.webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: nil)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's Swift 3:

```
    if let htmlFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "aa", ofType: "html"){
        do{
            let htmlString = try NSString(contentsOfFile: htmlFile, encoding:String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue )
            messageWebView.loadHTMLString(htmlString as String, baseURL: nil)
        }
        catch _ {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"marqueeMusic" ofType:@"html"];
```

It may be late but if the file from `pathForResource` is `nil` you should add it in the `Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
if let htmlFile = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("aa", ofType: "html"){
    do{
        let htmlString = try NSString(contentsOfFile: htmlFile, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding )
        webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString as String, baseURL: nil)
    }
    catch _ {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 2.0, @user478681's answer might look like this:

```
    let HTMLDocumentPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("index", ofType: "html")
    let HTMLString: NSString?

    do {
        HTMLString = try NSString(contentsOfFile: HTMLDocumentPath!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    } catch {
        HTMLString = nil
    }

    myWebView.loadHTMLString(HTMLString as! String, baseURL: nil)
```

Comment: better to use let to test against error in path/no file:

Answer (score 0):

Put all the files (html and resources)in a directory (for my "manual"). Next, drag and drop the directory to XCode, over "Supporting Files". You should check the options "Copy Items if needed" and "Create folder references". Next, write a simple code:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"manual/index" withExtension:@"html"];
[myWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

Attention to `@"manual/index"`, **manual** is the name of my directory!! 
It's all!!!! Sorry for my bad english...

=======================================================================

Hola desde Costa Rica. Ponga los archivos (html y demás recursos) en un directorio (en mi caso lo llamé manual), luego, arrastre y suelte en XCode, sobre "Supporting Files". Usted debe seleccionar las opciones "Copy Items if needed" y "Create folder references".

```
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"manual/index" withExtension:@"html"];
[myWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

Presta atención a `@"manual/index"`, **manual** es el nombre de mi directorio!!

Answer (score 0):

When your project gets bigger, you might need some structure, so that your HTML page can reference files located in subfolders.

Assuming you drag your `html_files` folder to Xcode and select the *Create folder references* option, the following **Swift** code ensures that the `WKWebView` supports also the resulting folder structure:

```
import WebKit

@IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "sample", ofType: "html", inDirectory: "html_files") {
    webView.load( URLRequest(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path)) )
}
```

This means that if your `sample.html` file contains an `<img src="subfolder/myimage.jpg">` tag, then the image file `myimage.jpg` in `subfolder` will also be loaded and displayed.

Credits: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8436281/4769344