# iPhone UIWebView loadHtmlString not added to history

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, back

My `UIWebview` loads a local html file using loadHtmlString.  The loaded page has links to other local html files as well as real links that use the internet.

I have added a back button with:

> if ([self.webView canGoBack])
>      [self.webView goBack];

This works fine except it does not recognise the original page loaded with loadHtmlString.

For example, if I navigate:
local -> local -> web
local X  local <- web  (The first back works, the next does nothing.)

How can I get the webview to recognise the original page so the back button also works for it?  Can I add it to the webview's history somehow?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would argue that `loadHtmlString:` is bad practice for all but the simplest use cases.  You should consider running a local web server instead.  I've had success with [CocoaHTTPServer](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer) and [Mustache templates](https://github.com/groue/GRMustache).  If you're able to write your entire app in HTML/JavaScript, consider using [Trigger.io](https://trigger.io/) or similar.

Comment: My use case was pretty simple.  Simply serving static pages as part of a book like format.

Comment: Static pages?  Great, save them to your bundle and use the technique I describe here http://stackoverflow.com/a/17557309/354144

Comment: Cheers Neal, good to know!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had a same problem. I tried manage the history, but it is error prone. Now I have discovered a better solution of this.

What you want to do is simply add a loadRequest to about:blank and make that as a placeholder for you before you call loadHTMLString/loadData. Then you are totally free from monitoring the history. The webview.canGoBack and canGoForward will just work. Of course, you will need a hack to handle go back to the placeholder about:blank. You can do that in webViewDidFinishLoad. Here is the code highlight:

In the function when you call loadHTMLString:

```
[weakSelf.fbWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"about:blank"]]];
[weakSelf.fbWebView loadHTMLString:stringResponse baseURL:url];
```

Code to handle goBack:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
  if ([webView.request.URL.absoluteString isEqualToString:@"about:blank"]
      && ![webView canGoBack] && [webView canGoForward]) {
    [weakSelf.fbWebView loadHTMLString:stringResponse baseURL:url];
  }
}
```

I think it is also possible expand this solution to handle those loadHTMLString that is not the first load. Just by having a Stack to record all the string response and insert an about:blank on each loadHTMLString. And pop the stack when each time go back to about:blank.

Comment: Nice solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

as [Cloud Xu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28226182/2529869) said you just need to preload dummy html, like this:

```
    webView.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "about:blank")!))
    webView.loadHTMLString("<html><body><b>Your page data</b></body></html>", baseURL: nil)
```

just it and nothing else! Swift3

Comment: loadRequest instead of load. Great answer!

Comment: @Nosov Pavel your solution work with ios 13... but below ios 13 it is not work

Answer (score 2):

Here's the workaround I ended up using:

I created a delegate for the WebView, which kept track of whether the user was on the first page (loaded using `loadHtmlString`).

When the back button is pressed, and the WebView can no longer go back, and the user is NOT on the first page, the first page is loaded again (using `loadHtmlString`).  Here is the relevant code:

```
if ([self.webView canGoBack])
    [self.webView goBack];
else
{
    WebViewDelegate * customDel = (WebViewDelegate *) self.webView.delegate;
    if (customDel.onFirstPage == NO)
    {
        // Load original local page.
        [self.webView loadHTMLString:self.htmlStr baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL]];

        customDel.onFirstPage = YES;
    }
}
```

I'll not choose this answer for a little while, in case a more elegant solution pops up.

Hopefully this helps someone!

Comment: what if user open your html page, click a link to another URL, then how can you toggle **onFirstPage** ?

Comment: I think it has a bug. Say you landed on site A with loadHTMLString. Then go to B, Then go to C. Then back to B, and back to A. Then if you goForward, it will go straight to C. B is missing

Answer (score 0):

You can also load just a [Data URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) with the HTML content you want to display, and avoid making an empty load and then loading the content separately.

The format is: `data:text/html,[HTML string]`

Ps. The HTML string must be percent encoded (URL encoded).

```swift
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
    let htmlString = """
<html>
    <body>
        hello world
    </body>
</html>
"""
    if let url = URL(string: "data:text/html," + (htmlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: []) ?? "")) {
        webView.load(.init(url: url))
    }
}
```