# Running web files inside an iOS App

Tags: iphone, ios, web

I'm working on a project that will need to be inside an iOS app as well as a website. It will need to run inside the app since it will must be accessed without a wireless connection.

Is it possible to run my web files inside the app without using something like phone gap?

Comment: Are you looking for something beyond UIWebView?

Comment: Not really wanting to view the site but rather run the web files inside the app itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the web connection for? Is it for user authentication? Is it for parsing data from a website? It really depends what you need an internet connection for, if you need some external data from a website or database then you would need to internally create some stores/sqlite db's to hold the data and sync that data when there is a connection.

If you are just running a client side app that you decided to create in HTML then I'd still use Sencha Touch, then Cordova to get it to compile natively.

You can always "Add to home screen" from Safari, to make it run locally. To do this, just visit the webpage when you have internet then add it to the homepage, it will run fullscreen without an internet connection; it will work fine offline IF AND ONLY IF you don't need to connect for any data.

Comment: It doesn't NEED an internet connection as it updates very rarely, maybe once a year, so updating files in the app is fine.

Comment: Could something like this be combined with a native app then? For example, say there is an app already that's a native iOS app but I want to add this function to the app using the Sencha Touch and Cordova as you suggested.

Comment: Hm, if you are just trying to get the exact html pages to load you could use a uiwebview and point to local html pages like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7063276/how-to-load-local-html-file-into-uiwebview-iphone ... did you consider the "add to home screen" option, I think that would work well here also. Although you  could not collect stats or money for it from the App Store that way.