# UIWebView Default no connection Page

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

Sorry for asking this silly question.

How can we load default safari page when not connected to the internet, like the page below, in our application?

[image]

Thanks in advance

Chahal

Comment: add some code of your webview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean : open a default page in the Safari application when taping on some button inside your application?
If yes, then here is the code :

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[YOUR_URL_HERE]]
```

Comment: Hi Helper, Thanks for help.  I was wondering, if there is a way we can load the above page within our application(with image and text "Safari cannot open the page because your iPhone is not connected to the Internet"), yes we can do that using custom images, but I was wondering if there is any code/setting we can load that page. Thanks

Comment: Hi Chahal, I don't know if there is a programmatical way of doing what you are requesting, but I'm pretty sure it's a "bad idea" since the view presenting the message will not be the true safari application.

Answer (score 1):

First check for an active Internet Connection [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083701/how-to-check-for-an-active-internet-connection-on-iphone-sdk), then load local html file into the uiwebview [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7063276/how-to-load-local-html-file-into-uiwebview-iphone).

Comment: Hi null, Thanks for your response. I am checking the internet connection for my application. If iPhone is not connected, rather than showing a blank page using method 

[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"about:blank"]]];

I was wondering, if there is a way we can load the above page(with image and text "Safari cannot open the page because your iPhone is not connected to the Internet"), yes we can do that using custom images, but I was wondering if there is any code/setting we can load that page. Thanks