# Marquee effect for labels in iOS

Tags: ios, text, uilabel, marquee

Is there any equivalent to the Android's `android:ellipsize="marquee"` for iOS? I've read some posts here regarding this scrolling text effect in iOS and it seems that you need either to implement the animation yourself with a timer, either use a third-party control, but those posts are a bit old and I need to make sure that the iOS SDK does not include a way to display this effect to its labels...

If the only way is to code it yourself or use another control, which control (open and free, and allowed for commercial apps) would you recommend?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You can do it only with the help of UIScrollView.

Answer (score 3):

You can use some think like `WebView` and apply the properties of scrolling on that `WebView` like this:

In android its seems like to be this:

```
String summary = "<html><body><marquee>This is basic example of marquee</marquee></body></html>";
webview.loadData(summary, "text/html", null);
```

The text will be moving from right to left.

I don't know how can I do it in **iPhone** or  **iOS**,

But by the same way you use it into your iOS `UIWebView` Object.

Hope this will be helpful for you.

You can also use JavaScript in `WebView` and can apply various type of scrolling.

Comment: Good trick! In iOS you should use `UIWebView` to load HTML into it. [Here's a reference link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7063276/how-to-load-local-html-file-into-uiwebview-iphone)

Comment: the answer should be updated to this: 
webview.loadHTMLString(summary, baseURL: nil);

Answer (score 3):

You can use **MarqueeLabel**:

Objective C and Swift: https://github.com/cbpowell/MarqueeLabel