# How to use JavaScript code in iOS?

Tags: javascript, ios

I have a block of javascript code for a like button with likebtn.com. I want to put this in iOS. I have been searching the web for hours but I couldn't find any way to simply use my javascript code in my xcode project. I need help making a vote  button. Thanks in advance

Comment: do you want to load the URL? or wants to write code?

Comment: i have a javascript code that makes a like button. i want it to make that button in an ios app

Comment: Did you try any code? or anything ?

Comment: i tried everything i found on the web but i couldnt find any tutorial to specifically use a javascript code in ios

Comment: please put some code that you tried

Comment: i followed this tutorial but i only had 'Hello World' and nothing more. I need more specific  explanation on how to use a javascript code:
http://sketchytech.blogspot.com.tr/2012/04/uiwebview-javascript-and-objective-c.html

Answer (score 0):

From interface builder drag UIWebView to your viewController.

Press ctrl and drag UIWebView connection to your h file to make IBOutlet.

[image]

Than in your m file you can access your UIWebView to load page content
Make sure to check https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_2 for full documentation

[image]

Comment: can you be more specific please

Comment: As an addendum: you might need to use stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:, see the reference [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:)

Comment: thanks very much for your help but i do not want to load page content i just want a javascript code to run

Comment: @deno But you also want to display HTML content generated from javascript (if i get it right) so you must use UIWebView –

Comment: and how to do that ? where should i place my javascript code.

Comment: You can put js inside file and load id to a webview
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7063276/how-to-load-local-html-file-into-uiwebview

or you can put your code in NSString and load it like [mWebView loadHTMLString:my_string baseURL:nil];

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the web view, you can execute javascript code using JavaScriptCore https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/WebKit_JavaScriptCore_Ref/_index.html

Some examples:
http://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/javascriptcore-and-ios-7/
http://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/javascriptcore-example/