# Parsing website html after java scripts are executed (Swift and OSX)

Tags: macos, swift

The following line of code works but returns the HTML code before executing the java scripts in the page.

```
var myContent = String(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: myURL)!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil) as String!
```

I've been researching this for a while but I'm having a hard time filtering out all the iOS noise (any advise on this would be highly appreciated).

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript code embedded in HTML is meant to be executed by a rendering engine such as a browser. when you download a HTML file (using String(contentsOfURL...)) you are doing exactly that - downloading the HTML file. There is no execution.

Once you download the file, you can then render the HTML file (for example, by loading it in a UIWebView - see [How to load local html file into UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7063276/how-to-load-local-html-file-into-uiwebview) for an example). Rendering the HTML file will "execute" the JavaScript based on how the HTML+JavaScript is authored.