# Bridge to pass data from Native to WebUrl

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, hybrid

I have following sneer

[storyboard view]==>[web view(open web url)]

Need to pass data from Native App to web url so it will fill its textfield and vice versa (https://github.com/dukeland/EasyJSWebView)

How i create html + javascript function so user can post data easily there from native app we post in `[PayU][1]` integration

What i need

1) HTML code with username , password field

2) javascript method to be call by native app to pass data to HTML form and display there

3) Calling using HTTP post like above payU integration type

NOTE: app should be native (not hybrid )

Helpful link: [load local html page in web view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7063276/how-to-load-local-html-file-into-uiwebview)

Comment: You will have to create plugin that will do the talking of native and js.

Comment: HTML code from backend where i can simply post data using HTTPPost url ?