# How to load html form to webview or safari?

Tags: ios, swift, webview

I'm getting a string response from the API of this format

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
    <form id="formRedirectToPayment" action="http://gate.666666pay.cn/cooperate/gateway.cgi" method="POST" target="_blank">

            <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="12.00" />

            <input type="hidden" name="clientIp" value="127.0.0.1" />

            <input type="hidden" name="expireTime" value="" />

            <input type="hidden" name="extra" value="payment" />

            <input type="hidden" name="merId" value="2018020911011185" />

            <input type="hidden" name="notifyUrl" value="http://fz.zf55555.com:8081/pfpay" />

            <input type="hidden" name="service" value="TRADE.H5PAY" />

            <input type="hidden" name="sign" value="004ABEFFA5D7458844AB4EAFD7C154BA" />

            <input type="hidden" name="summary" value="payment" />

            <input type="hidden" name="tradeDate" value="20180302" />

            <input type="hidden" name="tradeNo" value="PfQW180302200400018366QP" />

            <input type="hidden" name="typeId" value="3" />

            <input type="hidden" name="version" value="1.0.0.0" />

    </form>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById('formRedirectToPayment').submit();
</script>

</html>
```

Below is the code that sets the webview.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if let rootVC = navigationController?.viewControllers.first {
        navigationController?.viewControllers = [rootVC, self]
    }
    setWebView()
}


func setWebView() {
    webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: nil)
}
```

I would only get an empty webview with white background. If this can't work in webview I was thinking of loading the html string to safari, but it seems impossible.

Comment: Tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/7063407/6818278

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is the `form target` which is `_blank`, resolved this by implementing WKUIDelegate method and intercept links that request for a new webView.

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, createWebViewWith configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration, for navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, windowFeatures: WKWindowFeatures) -> WKWebView? {
   if (navigationAction.targetFrame?.isMainFrame)! {
      webView.load(navigationAction.request)
   }
   return nil
 }
```

Comment: Works like a breeze

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work using a WKWebView, but alas, you're still going to get a white screen, because **all of your form fields are hidden**.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

let htmlString = "<html><head><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" /></head><body><form id=\"formRedirectToPayment\" action=\"http://gate.666666pay.cn/cooperate/gateway.cgi\" method=\"POST\" target=\"_blank\"><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"amount\" value=\"12.00\" /><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"clientIp\" value=\"127.0.0.1\" /><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"expireTime\" value=\"\" /><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"extra\" value=\"payment\" /><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"merId\" value=\"2018020911011185\" /><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"notifyUrl\" value=\"http://fz.zf55555.com:8081/pfpay\" /><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"service\" value=\"TRADE.H5PAY\" /><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"sign\" value=\"004ABEFFA5D7458844AB4EAFD7C154BA\" /><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"summary\" value=\"payment\" /><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"tradeDate\" value=\"20180302\" /><input type= name=\"tradeNo\" value=\"PfQW180302200400018366QP\" /><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"typeId\" value=\"3\" /><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"version\" value=\"1.0.0.0\" /></form></body><script type=\"text/javascript\">  document.getElementById('formRedirectToPayment').submit();</script></html>"

class MyViewController : UIViewController {
    override func loadView() {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        self.view = view

        let webView = WKWebView(frame: view.bounds, configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration())
        webView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: nil)
        view.addSubview(webView)
    }
}
```

If you change `htmlString` to something like `<h1>Hello World</h1>`, it works fine.

You also won't be able to execute native javascript by loading HTML like this; instead, you'll have to add a `WKUserScript`:

```
let js = "document.getElementById('formRedirectToPayment').submit()"
let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
let userScript = WKUserScript(source: js, injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: false)
config.userContentController.addUserScript(userScript)
let webView = WKWebView(frame: view.bounds, configuration: config)
```