# Unable to load local HTML file in IOS

Tags: ios

I am trying load local HTML file in IOS using Xcode 4.6, but i am unable to load it, it's not showing anything on simulator

my code is

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"LocalPage" ofType:@"html"     inDirectory:nil];
    NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    [self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
}
```

Can any one please suggest me what is the problem?

Comment: Why are you using an outdated version of Xcode?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I load a local HTML file into the UIWebView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645414/how-can-i-load-a-local-html-file-into-the-uiwebview)

Comment: Does this web view ever get added to the view hierarchy?

Comment: Why are you getting string from file, instead of loading the file URL?

Comment: have you tried to load the file on _real_ device? not everything on the simulator works as same as on _real_ device.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing some error checking:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"LocalPage" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:nil];
    NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:error];
    if(htmlString)
        [self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
    else
        NSLog( @"error in loading string from file %@ - %@", htmlFile, [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

It may be that the .html file doesn't exist where you think it should be, or maybe it's an empty file.

Also, take advantage of the "`NSError`" parameter that you can use.

Answer (score 0):

You can load file by URL

```
NSURL *htmlURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"LocalPage" withExtension:@"html"];
[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:htmlURL]];
```