# UiWebView local HTML loading in offline situation

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview

```
I'm trying to load local HTML file in offline situation. I found a code here;

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645414/how-can-i-load-a-local-html-file-into-the-uiwebview
I'm using Reachability.h of Apple and it is working but I cant load local html file.
```

### I used to load local html with this codes

NSString *indexPath = [NSBundle pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:nil];
                [mWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:indexPath]]];

---

https://gist.github.com/FatihDurmus/dba74b42425fe0f71685acec7be12aa8
Here my controller code.

Comment: Add some code what you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code. It works.

```
NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"terms_en" ofType:@"html"];
webView.delegate=self;
NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

Hope this helps. :)