# Swift load html file in webview, change image size, font and text size

Tags: html, ios, swift, webview

Can anyone help me with add html file in webview? I want to present html data with my options of text size, font and image size.

I have this html code, it works when I add it in local file :

```
<style type="text/css">
    img {
        max-width: 348px !important;
    }
body {
    font-size: 15px !important;
    font-size: HelveticaNeue !important;
}
</style>
```

My question is how add this html code to each file I load from URL with swift?

Comment: You have to load as a request. look at this link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645414/how-can-i-load-a-local-html-file-into-the-uiwebview

Comment: Thanks Gagan for this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you want to add these html code at the end of a file, it's no problem. But as I know, the **style** needs to add in **head**, so I think you must *Analysis* the html string and find where to insert the **style**. The the problem is seem to be a string stitching.

```
let path = dir.stringByAppendingPathComponent(file);

//reading
let text = String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)

// Here you should insert the <style> string in text
// Or you just add the <style> at the end of the text

//writing
text.writeToFile(path, atomically: false, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
```